# ProxyPass Directive Issue

Tags: apache, tomcat

I've recently moved one of our sites to Apache 2.0 and Tomcat7 AWS and am having an issue with my ProxyPass directives

```
ProxyPass / http://10.1.1.1:8080/faith/                                     
ProxyPassReverse / http://10.1.1.1:8080/faith/
ProxyPass /images !                                                                                                          
ProxyPassReverse /images !                                                                                                                                              
Alias /images /var/www/html/sitea/images
ProxyPass /login !                                                                                                                                       
ProxyPassReverse /login !         
Alias /login /var/www/html/sitea/login
```

So if the URL is http://sitea.com then going to http://sitea.com works fine but http://sitea.com/images/ tries to resolve to http://sitea.com/faith/images/ whereas it worked fine on our other server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put bypassing of ProxyPass before actually serving from tomcat.

```
ProxyPass /images  !
ProxyPassReverse /images !   
Alias /images /var/www/html/sitea/images
ProxyPass /login !
ProxyPassReverse /login !         
Alias /login /var/www/html/sitea/login
ProxyPass / http://10.1.1.1:8080/faith/                                     
ProxyPassReverse / http://10.1.1.1:8080/faith/
```